# how to select table cell in mshtml.HTMLDocument for c# WPF WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#, facebook, wpf-controls

i would doing select in WPF Web Browser Control in mshtml.HTMLDocument.
but, i am in agony something to event. 
if user onclicked by Table, i would know selection cell. 
how to know select cell in table.

THIS CODE i confirm that table structure.

```
     IHTMLElementCollection tablecollection = doc.getElementsByTagName("table");
       foreach (IHTMLElement table in tablecollection)
       {
           System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(table.outerHTML);
       }
```